# Python: Replace for loops with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm fairly new at python and list comprehensions are not my strong point. However, I need some help reducing a nested for loop into a single statement like a list comprehension. What I have is:

```
 source_file_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6']
 test_file_list = ['file1', 'file3', 'file5']

 for i in range(len(source_file_list)):
    for j in range(len(test_file_list)):
        if test_file_list[j] in source_file_list[i]:
            file_match_list.append(source_file_list[i])
            break
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm trying to get rid of the "append"

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry about that, made the edit

Comment: @PatrickArtner The real contents of those list are thousands and thousands of source files and the tests used to get them. It's just the names of files that I can't reproduce. I'll make it a string instead

Comment: Why are you looping with indices if you don't really use them?

Comment: @superbrain I'm new and still trying to learn the best way to do things

Answer (score 1):

Use set intersections:

```
source_file_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6']
test_file_list = ['file1', 'file3', 'file5']

file_match_list = set(test_file_list).intersection(source_file_list)

print(file_match_list) # {'file5', 'file1', 'file3'}
```